# Errorbars look like pointrange (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I have the following data frame:

```
> df <- read.table("throughputOverallSummary.txt", header = TRUE)
> df
  ExperimentID clients connections msgSize      Mean Deviation     Error
1           77     100          50    1999 142.56427  8.368127 0.4710121
2           78     200          50    1999 284.22705 13.575943 0.3832827
3           79     400          50    1999 477.48997 44.820831 0.7538666
4           80     600          50    1999 486.87102 49.916391 0.8240869
5           81     800          50    1999 488.84899 51.422070 0.8462216
6           82      10          50    1999  15.23667  1.995150 1.0498722
7           83      50          50    1999  71.94000  5.197893 0.5793057
```

and some code that processes the dataframe df above:

```
msg_1999 = subset(df, df$msgSize == 1999)
if (nrow(msg_1999) > 0) {
    limits = aes(ymax = msg_1999$Mean + msg_1999$Deviation, ymin = msg_1999$Mean -   
    msg_1999$Deviation)
    ggplot(data = msg_1999, aes(clients, Mean, color = as.factor(connections), group =     
       as.factor(connections))) +
       geom_point() + geom_line() +
       geom_errorbar(limits, width = 0.25) +
       xlab("Number of Clients") +
       ylab("Throughput (in messages/second)") +
       labs(title = "Message size 1999 bytes", color = "Connections") 

    ggsave(file = "throughputMessageSize1999.png")
}
```

My problem is that the error bars in the plot look like pointrange. The horizontal bars at the upper and lower end of the error bars are missing.

[image]

Ideally, the error bars should have looked something like this:

[image]

Why do errorbars from my code look different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` parameter as the same scale as  `x`, you have given `width = 0.25`, where the range of the `x` axis is 0-800. A bar with width 0.25 is not going to be visible on this graph. If you don't set the width value, then something reasonably sensible is guessed.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(clients, Mean, color = as.factor(connections), group =     
                                as.factor(connections))) +
    geom_point() + geom_line() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Mean + Deviation, ymin=Mean-Deviation)) +
    xlab("Number of Clients") +
    ylab("Throughput (in messages/second)") +
    labs(title = "Message size 1999 bytes", color = "Connections")
```

[image]

Note that if you want to predefine your `mapping` argument, you should still specify the variables as you would within a call to `geom_xxxx`. `aes` (and `ggplot`) does some fancy footwork to ensure that this will be evaluated within the correct environment at the time of plotting.

Thus the following will work

```
limits <- aes(ymax = Mean + Deviation, ymin=Mean-Deviation)
ggplot(data = df, aes(clients, Mean, color = as.factor(connections), group =     
                                as.factor(connections))) +
    geom_point() + geom_line() +
    geom_errorbar(limits) +
    xlab("Number of Clients") +
    ylab("Throughput (in messages/second)") +
    labs(title = "Message size 1999 bytes", color = "Connections")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was way too sleepy to notice that width parameter.